# Generate array specific for each row of a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a while loop which generates all the inbox messages for a user, then inside that while loop, I have a query and another while loop which generate all the recipients of that message. I am trying to build up an array from that inside while loop which will echo all the recipients/participants of each individual message thread. As is, when I var_dump my usernamesarray, It gets built up to contain all the recipients of all the messages (by the final time it is echoed). SO, how would I go about making this array unique to each row? I am sure this is a common issue, but I cannot seem to find the search terms to learn much about it.

```
 if (count($numbermessages)) {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $getrecipusernames= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT distinct(message_recips.userid), users.username, users.id FROM message_recips INNER JOIN users ON users.id=message_recips.userid WHERE messageid=?");
            $getrecipusernames->bind_param('i', $messageid);
            $getrecipusernames->execute();
            $getrecipusernames->store_result();
            $getrecipusernames->bind_result($recipuserid, $recipusername, $recipuserid1);
            $getrecipusernames->fetch();
                 while ($getrecipusernames->fetch()) {
                      $usernamesarray[] = $recipusername;
                  }

            $date_time=$created_on;
            $dte_new=date("l H:i A", strtotime($date_time));
               if ($status=="A"){
            $message_read_status="read";
               }
            else {
            $message_read_status="unread";
            }
```

Sincere thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to declare the array prior to filling it, outside of the `while` loop:

```
 $usernamesarray = array();
 while($getrecipusernames->fetch()){
     $usernamesarray[] = $recipusername;
 }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer (even though it was posted by you).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count($numbermessages)) {
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $getrecipusernames= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT distinct(message_recips.userid), users.username, users.id FROM message_recips INNER JOIN users ON users.id=message_recips.userid WHERE messageid=?");
        $getrecipusernames->bind_param($messageid);//use one bind
        $getrecipusernames->execute();
        $getrecipusernames->store_result();
        $getrecipusernames->bind_result($recipuserid, $recipusername, $recipuserid1);
             while ($getrecipusernames->fetch()) {
                  $usernamesarray[] = $recipusername;
              }

        $date_time=$created_on;
        $dte_new=date("l H:i A", strtotime($date_time));
           if ($status=="A"){
        $message_read_status="read";
           }
        else {
        $message_read_status="unread";
        }
```

Comment: You have to bind that to a data type... And sorry if I'm confused, but this solution does not do anything towards the original issue.

Comment: you want to print inside the loop or out side the loop

Comment: I answered the question below. Thanks for checking it out.